# [FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/network-request-failed).]

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

Above error returned from Firebase when trying to run signInWithEmailAndPassword.

According to the Firebase docs the error is returned because:

> Thrown if a network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or
> unreachable host) has occurred.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.auth.Error

However, my other Firebase network requests are returned successfully.

Here's my code:

```
const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

  const signInWithEmailAndPasswordPress = async (email, password) => {
    try {
      console.log("PRESS");
      await signInWithEmailAndPassword(FIREBASE_AUTH, email, password);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
```

JS Calling function...

```
<TouchableOpacity
    style={styles.signIn}
    onPress={signInWithEmailAndPasswordPress}
>
<Text style={styles.buttonFont}>Sign In</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was developing my app on Android emulator at home.

Then I went out and connected to my cell phone's network. This Wifi change caused me `[FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/network-request-failed).]` error.

After restarting the Android emulator the error is gone.